# Extract parts of string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

My string is like

> COMMAND="HELP ME" TIMEOUT_SECONDS="30" APP_ID="SOMETHING RANDOM" COUNT="100" RETVAL="0" STDOUT="DATA I NEED" STDERR="NO ERROR" STATUS="SUCCESS"

I want to be able to extract `STDOUT`, `STDERR` and `STATUS`. How can I do it ?

Comment: My string is very orderly. If I get something specific it will be useful as I am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: ,,,,,,ta dah :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Still learning the trade :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
(?<=(?:STDOUT|STDERR|STATUS)\=")([^"]+)
```

As a result you will get 3 results.

```
MatchCollection mcol = Regex.Matches(strInput, @“(?<=(?:STDOUT|STDERR|STATUS)\=")([^"]+)”);

foreach(Match m in mcol)
{
   System.Diagnostic.Debug.Print(m.ToString());
}
```

Also:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/HokzpzHLp1)

Here, in this part of regex:

```
(?:STDOUT|STDERR|STATUS)
```

You can also specify the key (other than the 3 mentioned) whose value is needed.

Comment: Used this. Works like a charm. Even though escaping the escape sequence was painful.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input2 = @"COMMAND=""HELP ME"" TIMEOUT_SECONDS=""30"" APP_ID=""SOMETHING RANDOM"" COUNT=""100"" RETVAL=""0"" STDOUT=""DATA I NEED"" STDERR=""NO ERROR"" STATUS=""SUCCESS""";

var dict = Regex.Matches(input2, @"(.+?)=""(.+?)""").Cast<Match>()
          .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value.Trim(), 
                        m => m.Groups[2].Value.Trim());

Console.WriteLine(dict["STDOUT"]);
Console.WriteLine(dict["STATUS"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function:

```
public static Dictionary<string,string> GetValues(string command)
{
   Dictionary<string,string> output = new    Dictionary<string,string>();
   string[] splitCommand =  command.Split(" ");

   foreach(var item in splitCommand)
   {
      output.Add(item.Split("=")[0] , item.Split("=")[1]);
   }

  return output;
}
```

When you want to get the values use the function like

```
Dictionary<string,string> output = YourClass.GetValue(command);
string stdout = output["STDOUT"];
string etderr= output["ETDERR"];
string status = output["STATUS"];
```

I donot have access to compiler. So, there might be an error. But the overall functionality will look something like this.